# Any other way of saying "blah blah blah"

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

You might say "blah blah blah" when you're not interested in what'd be said.

I sometimes say "whatever" to convey the same idea, which does not share the nice rhythm effect of "blah blah blah". As a non-native speaker of English, I often pronounce "blah blah blah" in a very awkward way when speaking out very quick.

Any alternatives for "blah blah blah"?

Comment: "bleh bleh bleh"?

Comment: "If silence was golden, you couldn't raise a dime." ("Because your mind is on vacation and your mouth is workin' overtime") - Mose Allison

Comment: Are you talking about something that you would actually ***say** to the other person* (and how rude do you want it to be?), or are you talking about something that you would use after the fact to describe what the other person was saying?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Yadda yadda yadda" is one variant.

Comment: As are "Yeah yeah" "And so on and so forth", and "Etc., etc." in some circumstances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard "etc etc etc" quite often. It deserves to be an answer here.

Comment: @Terry: To be honest, I say it myself quite often. Normally meaning "I can't be bothered to say any more" rather than "...to listen to you". I do actually *like* "Yadda yadda" more, because it sounds ultra-dismissive to me - I just don't usually think to say it in time. Anyway, in principle ELU likes questions with only "correct" answer. I'm fully behind Bill's mule here, and by the votes so far it's looking good.

Comment: I thought it was ["yada yada yada"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Yada_Yada)

Comment: @LarsTech It's hard to get the spelling right on those nonsense words.  :)

Comment: Populair Seinfeld episode, The Yada Yada, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0697814/

Answer (score 3):

I've been known to make the "Charlie Brown's parents" sound (basicaly like a trumpet with a mute on it) with my mouth.

Comment: I've heard that used for incomprehensible speech (as opposed to speech one isn't interested in).  For example, our QA person sometimes says things like "I asked the developer why that happens and he said (Charlie-Brown noise goes here)", meaning the QA person is still in the dark.

Comment: Orthographically, "Wah wah, wah 'wah wah wah".

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I dunno. As a kid, I rarely had that much trouble understanding what my parents said. I always took it as meaning that it was relatively unimportant noises from another world (in this case, the world of adults).

Answer (score 3):

You can open and close your palm with your fingers straight. When you close, your thumb should touch your middle finger. All other four fingers should line up side by side. This looks like a chirping bird and basically means you speak too much, shut up. This is how your palm should look from sideways while performing the motion.

```
\        \
 \  ---.  \  ---.
 /  ---'  /  ---'
/        /
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm too dumb, but I can't follow your sense of humour here :(

Comment: @Terry: It's making your hand look like a duck opening and closing it's beak. Or opening the mouth of a hand puppet.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks Mitch. But anything to do with the question?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: Oh. As to meaning, it is mimicking someone talking a lot, in a deprecatory manner. It is often a hand gesture that goes along with 'yadda yadda yadda' or 'blah blah blah' (but not at all with 'etc etc etc') or behind someones back when one is bored with their incessant blather. This answer isn't really about English _language_, but about gestures in modern American culture (other cultures may easily use it but I don't know).

Comment: @Mitch So kind of you to solve my confusion!

Comment: I believe that in drama circles when background chatter was needed that the preferred method rather than them having actual dialogue was to repeat over and over "rhubarb rhubarb rhubarb". I don't have a reference though ...

Answer (score 2):

I have heard 'nah nah nah' used as well for this purpose (sometimes accompanied by placing ones fingers in their ears).

On the popular TV show *"how i met your mother"** a common way they showed disinterest was by placing the palm of their hand over their mouth and blowing to create a flatulent sound. This is generally viewed as more offensive than saying 'blah blah blah' as it is  alouder and more obnoxious sound.

*Yes, there is improper grammar in the title of the show.

Comment: I can't see the improper use of grammar in "how i met your mother" :(

Comment: haha the 'i' should be capitalized

Comment: ==! what about the first letter of "how"? lol

Comment: That is true as well

Answer (score 2):

They are not so short, but they do have a little rhythmic effect if you say them quickly:

- etcetera, etcetera, etcetera, ......
- and so on, and so on, and so on, ......

Answer (score 0):

boring, boring, and super boring! Did I mention boring yet?

- I think this could ( would) be a great prompt in a story! Here is my thoughts.....

My eyes are glued to the clock, two minutes until summer! Sweat trickles down my back, as I focus my eyes harder. All day I haven't listened to a word Mrs. Clark has said, It's not my fault! Whatever she says comes out like, " boring,boring, super boring! Did I mention boring yet?